# Both scrollbars highlight when hovering one

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

So I'm working on a custom style for a `ScrollViewer` control in my application. My style is included below and should be able to be copied and pasted in Blend.

The problem with my custom `Style` is that, when I hover over the vertical scrollbar, both the horizontal AND the vertical scrollbar highlight. When I after that hover over the horizontal scrollbar also both highlight. If I now want to highlight the vertical scrollbar again neither highlight.

So, both scrollbars highlight if I hover either the vertical or the horizontal one with the exception that neither do when hovering over the vertical after hovering over the horizontal first.

I have no idea why this happens. I think it's related to my `StoryBoards` in some way because when I leave the default `IsMouseOver` `Triggers` in it works fine.

Because the code is too big I had to put it on Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/g6n0fVyZ. Again, it's possible to just copy/paste the code into Blend and see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the **FillBehavior="Stop"** to ColorAnimation .see this article [`Timeline.FillBehavior`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior(VS.95).aspx)

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="Thumb.Leave.Action">
        <ColorAnimation FillBehavior="Stop" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle"
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                       To="#FFC9C9C9"
                       Duration="0:0:0.2" />
    </Storyboard>
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is partially solved. This fixes the problem with not highlighting the vertical scrollbar after hovering over the horizontal one. But this does not fix the problem that both scrollbars get highlighted if I hover either of them.